# searching for address of a system message

Tags: system-workflow-messages

I have a "Subscribe to our Newsletter form" that works fine. It replies to a new subscriber with a system message with the address:
https://my-website.org/civicrm/profile/view?reset=1&id=2109&gid=15&cs=b1e3576229a9f1640c7e52b6a06fbdc0_1708528073_168

Below is a screenshot of that page. I want to change the message in black and the Thank you message but I have no idea how to find the system template.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to use [grep](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/grep-command-in-linux-unix)? It's very handy for this. It shows the first one is:

**CRM/Mailing/Event/BAO/MailingEventSubscribe.php**:      `CRM_Utils_System::setUFMessage(ts('Your subscription request has been submitted for %1. Check your inbox shortly for the confirmation email(s). If you do not see a confirmation email, please check your spam/junk mail folder.', [1 => $groupTitle]));`

and the second is

**CRM/Profile/Form/Edit.php:**      `CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(ts('Your information has been saved.'), ts('Thank you.'), 'success');`

But I don't recommend editing core files. You could use [word replacements](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology) to change the strings just the match needs to be on how they are written in the code lines above. So e.g. the "Thank you" is a separate string from "Your information has been saved".

Comment: What if I want to add to this page something like, "Since you've signed up for our newsletter, how about Donating?" Is that in the realm of possibilities? Or do I have to tamper with core files?